# Connection String for Desktop App to external Web Server DB

Tags: c#, sql, database-connection, connection-string

I'm trying to get a working connection string from a desktop app to a db on an external (amazon) web server. Right now I'm getting a Login failed for user message which makes me think I'm close.

I can go to my DB on the server and login with a SQL login for "TestGuy" and run queries, so I know his credentials work

this is my connection string

```
 string remote = @"data source=ec2-54-234-254-230.compute-1.amazonaws.com,1433;uid=testguy;pwd=****;Initial Catalog=RMSScrum;Application Name=RMS;pooling=false";

+$exception {"Login failed for user 'testguy'."}    System.Exception {System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException}
```

I also opened port 1433 on my server, am I close or missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Close.

Did you open "Sql Server Configuration Manager"

1. SQL Server Network Config
2. Protocols for ..."
3. TCP/IP
4. IP Addresses Tab

You should see one that has the PUBLIC IP - make sure the Enabled box is set to "Yes" for that.  Secondary to that, ensure that the "IPALL" at the bottom has the dynamic ports blank and confirm that the TCP Port is 1433.

1. Could just be a connection string issue? http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/